# Add words to a local copy of WordNet

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I am using WordNet, accessed through Python's NLTK to compare the synsets of words from social media. Many of those words aren't in the version of WordNet that NLTK connects to.

When I say I *words* I mean domain-specific terms, not abbreviations or emoticons.

I've compiled a list of these words and would like to merge that list with WordNet.

Searching for prior efforts turns up on attempts to develop methods of automatically updating WordNet.

The steps I imagine are:

1. Clone the WordNet db
2. Write an extension of the WordNet module that looks for a local copy
3. Update that local copy.

How reasonable does this sound?

Comment: what "features" do you need from wordnet? do you need just the hypernyms or hyponyms or ids?

Comment: I want to calculate path similarity and so I need the hypernyms and hyponyms.

Comment: Looking at http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn-/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet-pysrc.html#WordNetCorpusReader. First find out where is the your nltk_data directory saved, `nltk.corpus.wordnet.root`. Then go to the directory and see how the file structures are like and and append your new synsets to the structure. It looks pretty complicated though =(

Comment: If you're just interested in retrieval, see http://pastebin.com/34ALzVuQ. You can also try to write a new path_similarity() function that parses through the data structure that is suggested by the code in the pastebin

Answer (score 2):

I haven't changed WordNet myself yet, but I had good experiences working with the [Multilingual Central Repository](http://adimen.si.ehu.es/web/MCR), and I believe you should be able to do what you want using that.

It contains the data files for WordNet 3.0 in several languages including English, which have been tied to each other through so-called Inter-Lingual Indexes (ILI). The data files can be loaded into a MySQL or PostgreSQL database tables, from which point it should be relatively easy not just to query it using SQL commands, but to insert new items, maintaining correspondence between tables. You can of course export the changed database as well, e.g. into CSV files, if using SQL is not enough for your purposes.