# Add new concepts to the WordNet using NLTK python API OR attach other concepts banks to WordNet

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, wordnet, language-concepts

I am working on a project where I want to retrieve the list of semantically similar concepts for a given sentence using WordNet and BERT. But there are some concepts which are not included in the WordNet. So I want to integrate my own list of concepts in the WordNet using python. But I am not able to do that. Kindly help me or suggest me the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a local copy of Wordnet and add your own words. More details here: [Add words to a local copy of WordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749730/add-words-to-a-local-copy-of-wordnet/65347258?noredirect=1#comment115528510_65347258)